# Dúvida GITHUB subdividindo o repositórios

Tags: git, github

Tem como eu criar uma pasta, e nesta pasta eu colocar os projetos separando por linguagem de programação?

Por exemplo, meus projetos em PHP
Eu crio repositório PHP, e lá vai estar...

site institucional, site mobiliária, site médico e a pessoa baixar somente o que quer? sem ter que baixar tudo?

E quando eu for dar um commit, subir nas pastas corretas?

[image: Eu faço assim no meu HD]

E dentro dele, fica os projetos, teria como fazer essa divisão?

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível. Quando você faz um commit, vc adiciona os arquivos, eles vão ficar exatamente nas pastas deles.

Ainda assim sugiro que você faça um repositório pra cada projeto: um pro site institucional, outro para site médico, mobiliária etc. Dessa forma fica mais fácil para navegar e entender cada projeto. (a não ser que esses projetos sejam relacionados, daí faria sentido agrupá-los em um único repositório)